# command substitution in openssl

Tags: shell, openssl, solaris, ksh, solaris-10

Trying to run this in ksh:

```
echo -n "string to encode" |
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass file:<(print -n 'somepassword')
```

keep getting error:

```
unknown option '/dev/fd/10'
```

what can I be doing wrong, I have searched but no answer.

Comment: Just what is `-pass file:<(print -n 'somepassword')` supposed to do?  Get a password from a file that's redirected from `stdin`? Even though you're already piping the output of another command to `openssl`? That makes no sense.  [The `openssl` passphrase options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html) are specifically designed to allow you pass a password that isn't visible to anyone on the system that runs `ps` - but your `print -n 'somepassword'` is visible to anyone on the system.

Comment: pass:password

    The actual password is password. Since the password is visible to utilities (like 'ps' under Unix) this form should only be used where security is not important.
env:var

    Obtain the password from the environment variable var. Since the environment of other processes is visible on certain platforms (e.g. ps under certain Unix OSes) this option should be used with caution.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Arguments to builtins are usually not visible to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Process substitution works differently in bash and ksh. Bash appends the result to the current word, ksh creates a new word:

```
$ cat testcase
showargs() { printf 'Arg: %q\n' "$@"; }
showargs file:<(echo -n foo)

$ bash testcase
Arg: file:/dev/fd/63

$ ksh testcase
Arg: file:
Arg: /dev/fd/3
```

I don't know whether ksh supports constructing arguments on the form that openssl requires it to be, so either use one of the other password passing mechanisms, use a temp file, manually open your own fd, or switch shell.

PS: `-d` means "decrypt".